# How to make editable fields in frontend for Django objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, frontend

I need to make objects editable in frontend by clicking on it and enable a form field to edit the text. i.e. in a ToDo-list which tasks can be edited by clicking on the task like shown in the following graphics:
[image: This is the regular frontend with "this is an example" subject]
[image: This shows the field if you hover over it]
[image: when click on the field, a form field allows to edit the text]

I am working with Django 2.x and unfortunately, I'm a little inexperienced.
Is it a good practice to realize this with REST API and/or Angular/React?
I would be glad about a few experiences, how something is feasible.

Comment: This can be done with only Django and Ajax. If this is the only reason you want to use Django Rest Framework, then don't.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good solution to implement the desired functionality with `Jeditable`

https://github.com/NicolasCARPi/jquery_jeditable